# What scriptures describe Lakshmi’s serpent Kalyana?

Tags: vishnu, puranas, sri-vaishnava, lakshmi

The Sharanagati Gadyam is a prose hymn by the famous Sri Vaishnava Acharya Ramanujacharya on the subject of Sharanagati, complete surrender to the lotus feet of Sriman Narayana as a means to attain Moksha.  In the first verse of the Sharanagati Gadyam, Ramanujacharya invokes Vishnu’s wife Lakshmi to intercede with Vishnu on his behalf:

> bhagavannārāyaṇābhimatānurūpasvarūparūpaguṇa**vibhava** 
>   aiśvaryaśīlādyanavadhikātiśaya asaṅkhyeyakalyāṇaguṇagaṇāṃ padmavanālayāṃ 
>   bhagavatīṃ śriyaṃ devīṃ nityānapāyinīṃ niravadyāṃ devadevadivyamahiṣīṃ
>   akhilajaganmātaramasmanmātaramaśaraṇyaśaraṇyāmananyaśaraṇaḥ
>   śaraṇamahaṃ prapadye ॥
>
> Having the form, beauty and splendour in consonance with and similar to that of Lord Narayana, having innumerable and unlimited amounts of wonderful and auspicious features such as **wealth**, splendour, glory and such groups of divine qualities, having the garden of lotus for her residence, Bhagavati, one who is always with the Lord, one who has no flaws, who is the queen and consort of the Lord of Lords, mother of this universe, our mother, refuge of the refugeless, I surrender to and seek refuge of that Sridevi and nobody else.

Now in his Rahasya Raksha, which contains a commentary on the Sharanagati Gadyam, Vedanta Desikan discusses two meanings for the word Vibhava or wealth here.  The first meaning is that it refers to the fact that both Lila Vibhuti the realm of Samsara and Nitya Vibhuti the realm of Moksha belong to Lakshmi, just as they as they belong to Vishnu.  The second meaning is that it refers to the fact that Lakshmi has her own unique ornaments and attendants, just like Vishnu does.

> sva-asadharana-vibhushadikam ca vibhavah “nidhih padmonidhih shankhuh chaturdandi gajastata kalyana sarpah pancasyah sikshito griharakshakah” iti ca purana prasiddhana anurupam iha yadarham grahyam
>
> And her wealth is her own unique ornaments.  The Puranas celebrate her with the verse “She has two treasures called Padmanidhi and Shankhanidhi, and a four-tusked elephant, and a **five-headed serpent named Kalyana**, and trained guards for her palace”.  In this verse she is shown to be suitably equal to Vishnu in her wealth.

I’m interested in the part in bold.  My question is, what scriptures describe Lakshmi’s five-headed serpent Kalyana?  It seems to be a counterpart to Vishnu’s serpent Adiseshan.

And does anyone know what Purana the verse quoted by Vedanta Desikan comes from?